# CE Image + Assets + S3 = Really Long and Ugly URL

Tags: assets, image, ce-image, s3, image-path

I'm using a combination of Assets (with S3) and CE Image to store and manipulate my images respectively.

Here's an example of the tag I use:

```
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{url}" width="1280" height="720" crop="yes" save_type="jpg" allow_scale_larger="yes" quality="81" cache="yes" refresh="360"}{made}{/exp:ce_img:pair}
```

And this is an example of the URL it produces:

```
http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/images/made/images/remote/http_s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/articles/imagefile.jpg
```

Is there any way to get around producing such a long and ugly URL when using these two add-ons together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this issue has been addressed multiple times in the support forums (and possibly already on EE Stack Exchange), but hopefully answering here too will be helpful to others down the road:

The long URLs are the automatic naming convention that CE image uses to prevent naming conflicts, and to mitigate the possibility of overwriting images. However, you can use [hide_relative_path=](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#hide_relative_path)"yes" and the [cache_dir=](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#cache_dir) param to have more control over your S3 URLs.

There are several other parameters in the documentation that give even more control over the cached (saved) image names and paths.